# Proftpd CentOS user can only login with a /bin/bash shell

Tags: centos, ftp, users, proftpd

I've created a user and assigned a password and group (new group). The problem is this user can only login to FTP (proftpd) if he has shell = `/bin/bash`

If I set the shell to `/bin/false` then Proftpd doesn't let him in and serves a 530 Login incorrect response.

I want the user to be able to login to FTP but no other access, so no access to login via SSH. The `/etc/proftpd.conf` is all defaults and it's version `1.3.3e`, and it's CentOS 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any shell you want to use with proftpd should be listed in the **/etc/shells** file (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_RequireValidShell.html)

You should add /bin/false to /etc/shells or set `RequireValidShell off` in the proftpd config

good luck!